# How to create working custom JSON parse exception mapping?

Tags: java, exception, jackson, jersey, mapping

I am using jersey-media-json-jackson-2.27 which has internal jackson.jaxrs.base where is JsonParseExceptionMapper which is used to send down a "400 Bad Request in the event unparsable JSON is received. But I want my own custom mapper.

I've created my own custom exception mapper.

I've already tried to set annotation @Priority(1), register it in my ResourceConfig like register(ApplicationJsonExceptionMapper.class) and with register(ApplicationJsonExceptionMapper.class, 1). Also I have  register(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class).

```
package com.application.provider;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;

@Provider
public class ApplicationJsonExceptionMapper implements 
ExceptionMapper<JsonProcessingException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(JsonProcessingException 
jsonProcessingException) {
        String responseMessage = "Invalid JSON";
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(responseMessage).type("text/plain").build();
}
```

}

Unfortunately when I send invalid JSON it still uses the built-in JsonParseExceptionMapper, do you have any ideas to try?

Comment: Do you register `JacksonFeature`?

Answer (score 1):

[`JsonProcessingException`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException.html) is the superclass of `JsonParseException`. So it makes sense that the mapper for `JsonParseException` is called for a `JsonParseException` being thrown. If you want to override it, then create your own mapper for `JsonParseException`. You will also need to create one for `JsonMappingException` as Jackson also has one for this also.

And Just FYI, so you understand how mappers are chosen, here's a quote from the JAX-RS spec

> When choosing an exception mapping provider to map an exception, an implementation MUST use the provider whose generic type is the nearest superclass of the exception.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've already tried that, forgot to mention that but no luck. What I think the problem is when it iterates the exception mappers (ExceptionMapperFactory) and choose one by lowest class distance it gets first to the built-in JsonParseExceptionMapper which will have distance 0 and will met the condition so it will never get to the custom made.

Comment: When combining this answer with 'register(ApplicationJsonExceptionMapper.class, 1)' it works for me.